# Single button multiple action

Tags: android

I am using a single button to do two task.

1. Watson Conversation.
2. Watson Text to Speech.

My code is executing only if my TextView has some Text name (string), but the Text to Speech is playing the last conversation response even though the new conversation response is updated at TextView display on my phone UI.. Continuation of this here [Race condition with UI thread issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936873/race-condition-with-ui-thread-issue)

Also I found out, if I keep my TextView empty i get error this:
[image] 
Code here:

```
private class ConversationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String textResponse = new String();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("in doInBackground");
        MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(params[0]).context(context).build();
        // async
        GLS_service.message("xxxxxxx", newMessage).enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {
                context = response.getContext();
                textResponse = response.getText().get(0);
                reply.setText(textResponse);
                System.out.println(textResponse);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            }
        });
        return textResponse;
    }
}

//
private class WatsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... textToSpeak) {
       /* runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(" ");
            }
        });*/
        TextToSpeech textToSpeech = initTextToSpeechService();
        streamPlayer = new StreamPlayer();
        streamPlayer.playStream(textToSpeech.synthesize(textToSpeak[0], Voice.EN_LISA).execute());
        return "Text to Speech Done";
    }
    /*@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText("");
    }*/
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Register the UI controls.
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    reply = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply);
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    new ConversationTask().execute("");

    //Button function
    send.setOnClickListener(action3);
}


  //five actions on button click
public void action5() {
    String textResponse = new String();
    System.out.println("Text to Speech:" + reply.getText());
    //textView.setText("");
    WatsonTask task = new WatsonTask();
    task.execute(String.valueOf(reply.getText()));
    //new WatsonTask().execute(reply.getText().toString());
}


View.OnClickListener action3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //action here//
        new ConversationTask().execute(input.getText().toString());
        action5();
    }
};
```

}

Please help.

Comment: provide code and errors not in pictures. you can post them formatted here

Comment: Added the code above. Please check

Comment: Have you tried to move your action5() logic to the onResponse inside the asyncTask?

Comment: action5() is executed before your ConversationTask is able to finish and update your reply - that is - you read the previous reply and start your WatsonTask, and after that the reply is updated with your ConversationTask result.

Comment: And btw you don't need to use "new String()". More common is to leave then unassigned (just `String textResponse;`) and let them be initialized as `null` or assign an empty string `String textResponse = ""` if you need a default non-null value. That way you avoid creating an unnecessary object.

Comment: @JuliánMartínez I tried the way you suggested, atleast the app is not crashing but the second task (action 5()) is not happening. I could only see the conversation reply on my screen. No voice out

Comment: @MarcinJedynak Thanks Marcin, you are right. This should work, but how do I only read the first TextView and start ny WatsonTask from the next on. Do advice.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not happening'? Is the sentence reached or just doesn't it work? I'll try to write an answer

Comment: @sabihataskin You should indeed use the way @JuliánMartínez suggested. BTW I see you use `enqueue` method in your GLS_service inside the AsyncTask. But you don't need both - you are already in the background thread. So either GLS_service enqueues the request and executes it in a thread it maintains or you should use a synchronous method inside the AsyncTask.

Comment: As in no "Voice out" is happening. The response of Watson Conversation has reached my UI, but simultaneously it should do a voice out too using my WatsonTask(). The second part of Voice out has not been played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action 3

```
View.OnClickListener action3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //action here//
        new ConversationTask().execute(input.getText().toString());
    }
};
```

Action 5

```
public void action5(String replyString) {
    WatsonTask task = new WatsonTask();
    task.execute(replyString);
}
```

Conversation Task

```
private class ConversationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String textResponse = new String();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("in doInBackground");
        MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(params[0]).context(context).build();
        // async
        GLS_service.message("xxxxxxx", newMessage).enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {
                context = response.getContext();
                textResponse = response.getText().get(0);
                reply.setText(textResponse);
                action5(textResponse);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            }
        });
        return textResponse;
    }
}
```

WatsonTask

```
private class WatsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... textToSpeak) {
        reply.setText(textToSpeak[0]);
        TextToSpeech textToSpeech = initTextToSpeechService();
        streamPlayer = new StreamPlayer();
        streamPlayer.playStream(textToSpeech.synthesize(textToSpeak[0], Voice.EN_LISA).execute());
        return textToSpeak[0];
    }
}
```

And for the sake of completeness address to the comment by Marcin Jedynak

Comment: thanks for the edit. I tried, but sill no Voice out.

Comment: @Juian The Audio is paying now, but no display of Conversation response at my phone UI

Comment: @sabiha taskin I've edited my answer, check it please

Comment: Thanks @Julian its working without a glitch. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Its working fine @Julian but there is a little issue which is after the audio is played out, my UI is updated with the display of Conversation response. I can ignore it but it shall be better if both display out and audio out happens simultaneously. So I thought of doing a `@Override protected void onPreExecute` at my WatsonTask but the code is not allowing me to do a `Override` there.

Comment: @sabihataskin answer edited. I just moved your reply.setText() from the onPostExecute to the doInBackground method

Comment: Thanks but i am getting error with the last edited code of WatsonTask. I get `Method setText must be called from the UI thread` Do we need to do a `onPreExecute()` ?

Comment: I get an error at `reply.setText(textToSpeak[0]);` newly added to WatsonTask. ERROR says: "`Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`"

Answer (score 0):

I think your program scenario will follow next sequences:

1. Enter text to conversation task.
2. Get conversation result from `GLS_service.message()`.
3. Input the result from sequence 2, for make the voice.

So try to change your code like this.

```
// There is no need to return String. Just send result to TextToSpeech.
//private class ConversationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private class ConversationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String textResponse = new String();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("in doInBackground");
        MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(params[0]).context(context).build();
        // async
        GLS_service.message("xxxxxxx", newMessage).enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {
                context = response.getContext();
                textResponse = response.getText().get(0);
                reply.setText(textResponse);
                System.out.println(textResponse);
                action5(textResponse); // It is real result that you want.
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            }
        });
        //return textResponse; // Not necessary.
    }
}

//
private class WatsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... textToSpeak) {
       /* runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(" ");
            }
        });*/
        TextToSpeech textToSpeech = initTextToSpeechService();
        streamPlayer = new StreamPlayer();
        streamPlayer.playStream(textToSpeech.synthesize(textToSpeak[0], Voice.EN_LISA).execute());
        return "Text to Speech Done";
    }
    /*@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText("");
    }*/
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Register the UI controls.
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    reply = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply);
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    new ConversationTask().execute("");

    //Button function
    send.setOnClickListener(action3);
}


  //five actions on button click
// Need a parameter to get String.
//public void action5() {
public void action5(String text) {
    // String textResponse = new String(); // Replace to parameter as "text".
    //System.out.println("Text to Speech:" + reply.getText());
    System.out.println("Text to Speech:" + text);
    //textView.setText("");
    WatsonTask task = new WatsonTask();
    //task.execute(String.valueOf(reply.getText()));
    task.execute(text); // Replace to parameter as "text".
    //new WatsonTask().execute(reply.getText().toString());
}


View.OnClickListener action3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //action here//
        new ConversationTask().execute(input.getText().toString());
        // action5(); // This invoking is not necessary at this point.
        // Try to invoke this method after you get conversation result.
    }
};
```

If it is not working even you changed, I want to know how you implement `initTextToSpeechService()` method.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks you are right with the sequence. I tried your code but Voice is not played. Also I made a change in ConversationTask()you provided: protected  Void doInBackground(String... params) .

Comment: My `initTextToSpeech()` is : `private TextToSpeech initTextToSpeechService() {
        TextToSpeech service = new TextToSpeech();
        String username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        service.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
        service.setEndPoint("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api");
        return service;
    }`

Comment: Also I dont see `System.out.println("Text to Speech:" + text);` in my console

Comment: My audio is out, but i dont see my conversation response on my phone UI.